# Making changes to a git submodule

Tags: git

I have a project with a third party submodule of which I am not a contributor of.

I had to make changes to some of it's files, namely some project files, so that I could target a different platform (original project targeted mono, while I have switched to dotnet core), yet I still want to be able to merge the latest changes of the original submodule repository.

Using a normal setup of just having the project as a submodule, I cannot successfully clone my project because git will not find the commits I've made in the original repository:

```
Server does not allow request for unadvertised object <my_commit_id>
Fetched in submodule path <submodule>, but it did not contain <my_commit_id>
```

I would like to do something similar to the command git `submodule update --remote --rebase`  in which the changes I've made to the submodule will be written on top of the new ones from the original remote, but I want to be able to commit the changes I made to my super project so that when I clone the repository the changes will be applied on top of the submodule.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule is a repository: you can replace it with [a fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo), which can:

- be added an `upstream` remote which reference the original repository
- be completed with `upstream` commits (`git fetch uptream`)
- be reset to upstream/master
- be updated with the commits you have done (`submodule update --remote --rebase`, with your `origin/master` of your fork being rebased on top of local `master`, which was reset to `upstream/master`)

Answer (score 0):

A submodule *is* a Git repository.  It's just a Git repository that some other Git—the *superproject*—will `git clone` for you and then `git checkout` some particular commit (as a "detached HEAD" in the submodule).

Anyone who clones the superproject will at some point run `git submodule update --init`.  That will have the superproject run `git clone` to obtain the submodule Git repostiory.  Any commits you made in *your* clone are ... well, in *your clone*.  They're not in any other clone.  So you'll have to give everyone on the Internet—or at least, everyone who might `git clone` your superproject—access to *your* clone of that submodule.

If you don't want to give the entire Internet access to your laptop—and you probably don't—you *must* stop keeping the only copy of the submodule repository on your laptop.  In other words, you need a *public-access version of the submodule*.

Let's suppose the submodule you cloned yesterday is `https://github.com/someone/sub.git`.  Your laptop clone of this submodule, `file://path/to/sub.git`, has no generally-accessible-from-the-Internet URL (`file://...` on *my* laptop refers to *my* files, not yours).  So what you need to do is make, on GitHub or wherever, *your fork* of that submodule: `https://github.com/bodhi_daruma/sub.git` or whatever that may be.

Now that you *do* have a public-access version of `sub.git`, you can send your submodule Git commits *to* that repository.  You'll probably want to make your submodule commits, on your laptop, in a *branch*, rather than using the "detached HEAD" mode that your superproject set.  See existing questions about how to do that.  Then you'll `git push` the commits you made in your submodule on your laptop, to the Git on GitHub (or wherever it is you are keeping this).

Now you'll want to have your *superproject* Git refer to `https://github.com/bodhi_daruma/sub.git`, or whatever the URL is, rather than `https://github.com/someone/sub.git`.  That is, when people clone your superproject, that clone will direct *their* superproject Git to `git clone` your fork of the submodule.

The only other real alternative is to propose to whoever maintains the submodule you're using that they incorporate your commits into their (GitHub-or-whatever) repository.  That probably *also* involves using the fork feature on GitHub or Bitbucket or wherever this submodule repository resides.